# Height difference among taskpanes in Excel Online

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-addins

## Problem Description:

Taskpanes of an add-in may have different height in Excel Online, as a consequence, content may be hidden on the bottom.

## My Environment:

System: windows 10

Browser: Chrome

## How to Reproduce:

Open Excel Online in chrome, then open two addin taskpanes first (for example: Script Lab).

1. hide them all, then click to open any one of them, you can see the shown taskpane's height is `660px`. the hidden one's height is `770px`.

[image: 1]

(In the above picture, for distincting the height difference, I hide all the taskpanes -> open Taskpane 1 -> show Taskpane 1 in the end.)

2. following Step 1, don't hide the opened taskpane, just click the tab of the hidden taskpane and let it show, you will see the height of two taskpane all become `710px`, which is beyond our visual height (it should be `660px`).

[image: 2]

(In the above picture, to distinguish the height difference, I hide all the taskpanes -> then open Taskpane 2 -> open Taskpane 1 -> show Taskpane 1 in the end.)

As you can see in these two pictures, the height difference leads to content overflow in Picture 2 on the bottom, the footer disappears.

I don't know how to write my addin's css to let it work as normal. Even in the Script Lab official add-in, it's still a problem.

It seems that the problem does not come from Excel add-ins; it should be fixed in Excel Online. Could any one give some help? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

This indeed seems to be a bug in the Excel Online platform (and we have a tracking bug for it in Script Lab as well, https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/issues/382#issuecomment-444013605).  Let me ping some folks on that team to see if there is an update on this...